# cómo guardar un array en la base de datos de laravel?

Tags: laravel, fetch

estoy enviando por fetch de javascript un array como este:

```
{"3":{"id":"3","name":"LavandaEcon.","precio":"17000","cantidad":1,"cliente_id":"1","document":"144","iva":0},
"4":{"id":"4","name":"OceanFresh","precio":"24920","cantidad":1,"cliente_id":"1","document":"144","iva":0}}
```

para recibirlo en mi controlador en el metodo store y guardarlo en la base de datos asi:

```
foreach($request as $item){
    $newDocument = new Document();
    $newDocument->user_id = auth()->id();
    $newDocument->cliente_id = $request->cliente_id;
    $newDocument->product_id = $request->id;
    $newDocument->amount = $request->cantidad;
    $newDocument->document = $request->document;
    $newDocument->price = $request->precio;
    $newDocument->iva = $request->iva;
    $newDocument->save();
}
```

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que lo que te llega es un array de json por el request? Igual si es un array, debería ser: `$request->name['key']` porque en la manera que lo haces, estoy viendo que son propiedades que están dentro del objeto Request

Comment: intenté con $request->$item['id'] tambien con $item['id'] y desde mi vista lo convierto primero con let enviarJson = JSON.stringify(variable) para asegurarme que se envíe en json, aunque también lo intente enviando el objeto sin convertir a JSON y nada me funciona... por favor otra ayudita

Comment: Parece que estas tratando de usar el request para traer todos los elementos del json, lo que te aconsejo es que cuando hagas el envío de datos, envies un key => data, por ejemplo, { documents: {"3"....} } de esta forma usas el foreach asi `foreach($request->get('documents') as $item)`

Comment: Si haces json.stringify, conviertes el json en un string. Es obvio que si tratas de acceder a una propiedad de tu json, no lo vayas a lograr porque estás recibiendo un string

Answer (score -1):

Lo solucioné desde el front end haciendo lo siguiente:

```
Object.values(miObjeto).forEach(p=>{
  // aqui puse un fetch para que hiciera la consulta a el backend por cada objeto
}
```

Gracias gaidyjg por tu ayuda en los comentarios